# Unable to expand user-defined macros on ClojureScript

Tags: macros, clojurescript

I am having trouble writing and debugging marcos with ClojureScript since `macroexpand` refuses to expand my macros. I could reproduce the problem at http://clojurescript.net:

```
cljs.user=> (macroexpand '(int 5))
(js* "(~{} | ~{})" 5 0)
cljs.user=> (defmacro macro-test [i] "not i")
true
cljs.user=> (macro-test 1)
"not i"
cljs.user=> (macroexpand '(macro-test 1))
(macro-test 1)   <-- :(
```

Locally I am running `org.clojure/clojurescript "1.10.773"`. It is odd that built-in macros seem to work. Any help or explanations would be appreciated. Do I need to write my macros in a Clojure environment rather than ClojureScript?

Comment: I read somewhere (a long time ago now) that macro expand in clojurescript will not expand in the REPL environment. IIRC, this is link to the fact that you cannot define a macro in a ".cljs" file. To be accessible in clojurescript, a macro have to be defined in a ".clj" or a ".cljc" file. I'm pretty sure this subtlety is described on the official site of clojurescript.

Comment: I found [this](https://gist.github.com/alandipert/4669472) from 8 years back. "To write ClojureScript macros, one must write them in Clojure and then refer to them in ClojureScript code."

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it seems that macros aren't "fully" implemented on the CLJS side. [This](https://code.thheller.com/blog/shadow-cljs/2019/10/12/clojurescript-macros.html) is a relatively new article from Oct 12, 2019.

> First of all - ClojureScript macros are written in Clojure and run
> during the ClojureScript compilation on the JVM. A macro is just a
> function that takes code (as simple data) and generates other code
> (again simple data) out of it. The CLJS compiler will then turn the
> result into JS. This is done in Clojure so that the generated JS does
> not need a full ClojureScript compiler at runtime.

And

> ClojureScript macros are written in Clojure and run on the JVM

So some tricks seem to be necessary, which is a pity since I expected "all" Clojure code to work directly in ClojureScript the same way.

Edit: In case anyone else is wondering how to code and debug macros in a CLJS project, you should write them in a .cljc file and do the debugging in a Clojure REPL session. My Calva REPL started in a CLJS mode, but there is a toggle command to switch between that and CLJ. However it did not have an immediate effect, I think I had to do the jack-in again.

Comment: You have several differences between clojure and clojurescript. Particularly about macro. From the official website: https://clojurescript.org/about/differences#_macros